# Matlab Compiler linking errors (64 bit versus 32 bit)

Tags: c, matlab, static-linking, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have been using the deploytool in Matlab for the past few months in my 2010b 64bit version of Matlab. I just recently found out that I need to create a 32 bit version of my c shared library.

To do this I follow the same methods I had been using previously (pretty much calling the command `mcc -W lib:MYLIB -T link:lib -d 'MYOUTPUTFOLDER' -v 'MFILE1' 'MFILE2'`) in my 2009b 32 version of Matlab. I keep getting the error LNK1811: cannot open input file LIBRARY.obj. I have tried to find this LIBRARY object file but I cannot seem to find it anywhere.

So far I have checked to ensure all of the correct libraries are available (found at $MATLABROOT$\extern\include\win32), I have made sure all of my paths are correct in the compopts.bat file, and I have used the option -T compile:lib which works fine and creates a dll. This would be great but I need a lib file to use later in mbuild.

My current path forward is to take the compopts from my 64 bit version of Matlab (on a different machine) and compare it with my compopts for the 32 bit. I will post if it makes a difference.

Comment: Have you tried running `mcc` from the dos shell. May be forcing for $MATLABROOT$\bin\win32\mcc.exe and for expected `compopts.x32.bat` file with `-f` option. When compiling for both arch from same machine, matlab overwrites same `compopts.bat` (letting `mbuild -setup` create it for me) ... so i ended up forcing everything in my deploying scripts ... _well here you say you're using two separate machines_ :( ...

Comment: I tried running mcc from the dos shell just now and it returned the same errors. I also tried my approach above and changed some of my 32bit compopts to what they were in 64 bit land which also did not work.  I am not quite understanding your second sentence about forcing for $MATLABROOT$\bin\win32\ mcc.exe and for expected `compopts.x32.bat` file with -f option, is this something that would have been fixed with the dos shell run or do i need to fix  the mcc.exe?

Comment: On compilation PC I have both x64 and x32 versions of matlab so depending on which arch I want to build I either force scripts to point to `~\win32\mcc.exe` or `~\win64\mcc.exe`. For `compopts.bat` file, I created one with matlab x64 (`mbuild -setup` => renamed to `compopts.x64.bat`) and one with matlab x32 (`mbuild -setup` => renamed to `compopts.x64.bat`). I then again force correct one on mcc command line with the `-f` option *(If not specified mcc.exe uses last generated `compopts.bat` [and as matlab x64/x32 generate this file on same disk location it can be the wrong one])*

Comment: Typo: _For x32 should read renamed to `compopts.x32.bat` of course_

Comment: For x32 I use `lcc` as compiler, and for x32 I use `VS2012`. I Would have like to use `lcc` in both cases (to avoid having to deploy VC redistributables), but unfortunately matlab does not provide for `lcc` in x64 mode (R2013b for me).

Comment: Gotcha, that makes a lot of sense. Over the weekend I was able to obtain the x32 version of Matlab on the same computer as my x64 so I am glad to have this approach in mind. Unfortunately, I am forced to use VS because of requirements for the project :/ (P.S. I think your last comment meant to read: For x32 I use lcc as compiler, and for **_x64_** I use VS2012.)

Comment: Great... Yes for **_x64_** I use VS2012, very annoying ... so don't forget to deploy redistributables that correspond to your version of VS within the installer (This avoids long debug with customers saying _The specified module could not be found_)

Comment: Good point, I will make sure not to forget about those. I was going to type up your comments into a answer for the question so future visitors can see easily find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize our comments in the question and make it an answer. Here is how I manage to create both x32 and x64 libraries/standalones with mcc.

NB: *Maybe there are more elegant solutions to configure deploytool, anyway with brute force I'm sure it works and I can automate global deployment process for my applications ...*

**Machine setup**

1. Install Matlab x32 and x64 on your machine
2. Run Matlab x32 and setup compiler options typing `msbuild -setup`

   - This will generate a `compopts.bat` file in `~user\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2013b` *(path may differ upon your version)*
   - Rename this file to `compopts.x32.bat` *(see later)*
3. Run Matlab x64 and setup compiler options typing `msbuild -setup`

   - This will generate a `compopts.bat` file in `~user\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2013b` **(!!Overwrites x32!!)**
   - Rename this file to `compopts.x64.bat` *(To workaround file overwrite)*

**EDIT** *Just tested ... In R2014b, Matlab does no longer overwrites same `compots.bat` file ... it now generates two separate `MBUILD_C++_win64.xml` and `MBUILD_C++_win32.xml` files (which is a good thing!).*

**Compilation in x32**

Force your compilation script to point to `~matlabx32\bin\win32\mcc.exe` and force `mcc.exe` to use previously saved `compopts.x32.bat` file using the `-f` option. Your command line should be something like:

```
~matlabx32\bin\win32\mcc.exe -f "compopts.x32.bat"  ... other mcc options ...
```

**Compilation in x64**

Force your compilation script to point to `~matlabx64\bin\win64\mcc.exe` and force `mcc.exe` to use previously saved `compopts.x64.bat` file using the `-f` option. Your command line should be something like:

```
~matlabx64\bin\win64\mcc.exe -f "compopts.x64.bat"  ... other mcc options ...
```